# Getting error while running simple javascript using node framework

Tags: javascript, node.js

As I run this piece of code using `node a.js`:

```
var sys = require('sys');
sys.puts('Hello, World');
```

I'm getting the following as an error

> axconfig: port 1 not active
>
> axconfig: port 2 not active

Comment: I find it unbelievable that this thing is - after more than 2 years - still an issue even in the biggest magazines: currently nettuts (millions of readers) says you should install node.js via apt-get install node. holy ! http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/node-js-for-beginners/comment-page-1/#comment-426442

Comment: Leaving a comment on this old post in case it helps anyone.  The answers are all assuming that the issue is node was installed "incorrectly", but there are also cases where the "node" package and node.js need to live side-by-side. This can be the case for example on Ubuntu servers if you are not the administrator.  Even if you know to run "nodejs" instead of "node" on an Ubuntu system, this issue can pop up due to scripts assuming that the command to run node.js is "node"

Answer (score 90):

**Warning: This is old but it might still work.**

You didn't install node.js but the package *node* (that contains some other unrelated software) for your linux distro.

You can install node.js three ways: Using git, downloading the version file, or installing through the package manager, I recommend using the package manager for ease-of-use and the ability to easily update.

**Package Manager**

Check out [Installing Node.js via Package Manager](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager). It has instructions on how to install using the package manager of your preference.

**Direct Download**

Go the the [downloads page](http://nodejs.org/download/) of node.js and download the package for your OS. Don't forget that, doing i this way, doesn't auto-update node.js later on!

**Source Compilation / git**

First you need git and a compiler, here is how you install them on debian/ubuntu (this depends on your package manager):

```
sudo apt-get install git-core build-essential
```

(If you don't want to use git, you can download the source code from the website. You still need build-essential or equivalent for your OS.)

Then go to a folder where the "node" repository will be placed, something like `~/projects` or `~/src` is good enough, and do this:

```
git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
```

Then enter the node directory, configure it and build it.

```
cd node && ./configure && make
```

Everything should go well. Before installing node you can optionally run the tests to check for any problems:

```
make test
```

You can finally install node, this allows you to run the node command anywhere in the system and the javascript libraries to be installed.

```
make install
```

...and we are done.
You can test those lines of code using node-repl (node's [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop), think "interactive interpreter"), just type `node-repl`, quit with *Ctrl+D*.

Comment: you also need to install the package `curl`

Comment: Better yet, download a stable release from nodejs.org and install that. A lot faster then cloning the full Git repo.

Comment: Ubuntu has an easy way to install it as well.  https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

Comment: sudo apt-get install nodejs does not install anything. nowhere.

Comment: sudo apt-get install nodejs says "couldn't find package"

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it now. Someone forgot that not everyone uses Ubuntu.

Answer (score 34):

> axconfig: port 1 not active 
>   axconfig: port 2 not active

this problem no where related to nodejs.

Do not install node using the command `sudo apt-get install node`, This will install radio package(node). this radio package requires axports to be active, which is not linked with nodejs

So uninstall node from `sudo apt-get remove node`

Manually Download nodejs from [Here](http://nodejs.org/) or from [GitHub](https://github.com/joyent/node.git) but make sure you install the stable branch(0.4.x).Unpack the nodejs.

For installing please follow the `README.md`

After installing then set the environment variables `echo PATH=$PATH:/home/user/pathtonode/`

Comment: Note the typo in PATH=$PTATH. Should be PATH=$PATH if it's not obvious.

Answer (score 11):

you installed node, you want the package called nodejs

Comment: Precisely... I'd installed node in over 20 machines and the latest attempt I made this mistake.

Answer (score 11):

If you are on ubuntu, follow:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

You need to install nodejs and not node!

Comment: can you please differentiate between borh nodejs and node

Answer (score 6):

**Brandon Helwig** is correct. It just happened to me. In general, if you get this type of error, you have installed the wrong package. Here are more instructions for you to install one of the latest versions of Node.js.

**Fix**

```
sudo apt-get remove node
```

This will remove the accidentally installed package. Both names for the package `node` and `nodejs` are the same which is `node`.

If you do `sudo apt-get install node`, what you would get is a old version. But thanks for Chris Lea, we got a PPA for this task.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

This should get you the latest version of `Node.js` in your application.

If you are in need of an bleeding edge version, you can install from the source. But I think this is way cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is occur in ubuntu,so I resolved this problem by git. Clone this new source from github
and do following actions:

1. Uninstall node

   sudo apt-get remove --pure node
   sudo apt-get clean
2. Make install node

   git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
   cd node
   ./configure
   make
   make install

Then this will be work well.

Answer (score 0):

If Node.js installation as suggested by ninja works for you (like on AWS Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

you might still want to add node to your system path like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH
```

so you can type

```
node webapp.js
```

instead of

```
/usr/bin/node webapp.js
```

Find your node installation path simply by typing

```
which node
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to remove the node installation first and then install npm.
npm is the Node Package Manager, this will automatically install nodejs itself