# Error while installing express using npm

Tags: node.js

I already have installed express using

```
npm install express
```

but looks like in order too create apps I should install it globally. So I used:

```
npm install -g express
```

but received:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/express'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/express']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/express',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/express',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/lib/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/lib/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.2-201.fc19.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "express"
npm ERR! cwd /home/parisa
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/express
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/lib/node_modules/express
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/express'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/parisa/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

then after trying sudo:

```
sudo npm install -g express
```

I get this:

```
axconfig: unable to open axports file /etc/ax25/axports (No such file or directory)
```

why is that???

Comment: You haven't installed node correctly more than likely. You've installed something called Node, when in fact, you wanted NodeJS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424346/getting-error-while-running-simple-javascript-using-node-framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error clearly states, you don't have permissions to create in /usr/lib.
    stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/express'

hence install with sudo permissions..

```
sudo npm install -g express
```

Comment: You should never use `sudo` with npm!

Comment: @MohamedTurki that's debatable. Anyway I don't install packages globally this way, I install via `npm install -g express --prefix ~/node_modules`. I have all node modules inside ~/node_modules instead of /usr/lib/node_modules.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using fedora?

At least in fedora the "node" package is **not** node.js, It is an amateur radio utility,
axconfig is a file of that software.

npm is not finding nodejs, it is trying to use the wrong software.

Install nodejs package

```
sudo yum install nodejs
```

and remove node package

```
sudo yum remove node
```

Now npm must work properly for the super user.

edit: Also in debian repositories, the package 'node' is not nodejs

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Arch Linux, check out the `npm2arch` package in the AUR. It will let you install npm packages using pacman.

Example:

```
npm2archinstall express
```